# Is there any option that we can turn on access to my location in Location Services in android mobile settings from application?

Tags: android, location, settings, android-permissions

I want to turn on Settings>>Location Services>> Acess to my location in mobile from application.Is there any permission in android for that.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Your question is not clear what do you want to do? Do you want to access location or do you want to open the setting screen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Recent android device has no permission to change system setting from normal application.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html

> Secure system settings, containing system preferences that applications can read but are not allowed to write. These are for preferences that the user must explicitly modify through the system UI or specialized APIs for those values, not modified directly by applications.

Instead of change settings directly, you can lead user to specific settings Activity to change settings by their own by `Intent` with `Settings.ACTION_*`s.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my application. If Device location service is turn off then this method go to setting and you can turn on location service.

```
if (!locationmanager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();
        }

private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.gps_warning))
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.enable), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                       startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                   }
               });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> No, from application which are (not system apps) we cannot
>   programmatically turn location service ON

We only can open location settings to user to turn the settings manually ON